# Adding csv file values from one column but from certain rows, with python

Tags: python, csv

I've got a housing csv that looks like this:

```
year,title_field,value
2014,Total Housing Units,49109
2014,Vacant Housing Units,2814
2014,Occupied Housing Units,46295
2013,Total Housing Units,47888
2013,Vacant Housing Units,4215
2013,Occupied Housing Units,43673
2012,Total Housing Units,45121
2012,Vacant Housing Units,3013
2012,Occupied Housing Units,42108
2011,Total Housing Units,44917
2011,Vacant Housing Units,4213
2011,Occupied Housing Units,40704
2010,Total Housing Units,44642
2010,Vacant Housing Units,3635
2010,Occupied Housing Units,41007
2009,Total Housing Units,39499
2009,Vacant Housing Units,3583
2009,Occupied Housing Units,35916
2008,Total Housing Units,41194
2008,Vacant Housing Units,4483
2008,Occupied Housing Units,36711
```

I need to use Python to take the number of Occupied Housing Units in 2009 and subtract it from the number of Occupied Housing Units in 2008 (and so on, up to 2014) and return the values in ascending order.

I'm in a class where this wasn't taught, but this is expected, and I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around how to hone in on a specific "cell" to work with it.

Here's all I have.  It returns each row as a list, which is nice, but I'm lost beyond that.

```
with open('housing.csv', newline='') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: do you know how to use a dictionary? `csv.DictReader` will give you a dictionary for each line, with the keys being the name of the column and the values being the entry in the row. Its a little nicer to work with imo, since you don't have to index into a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas` for this task:

```
df[df['title_field'] == 'Occupied Housing Units'].groupby(by= \
['year','title_field']).sum().diff(-1).sort_values('value', ascending=False)

                              value
year title_field                   
2008 Occupied Housing Units   795.0
2010 Occupied Housing Units   303.0
2011 Occupied Housing Units -1404.0
2012 Occupied Housing Units -1565.0
2013 Occupied Housing Units -2622.0
2009 Occupied Housing Units -5091.0
2014 Occupied Housing Units     NaN
```

If you want `absolute` values it becomes:

```
df[df['title_field'] == 'Occupied Housing Units'].groupby(by=
['year','title_field']).sum().diff(-1).abs().sort_values('value', 
ascending=False)
```

Changing the column name of the first column isn't so straight forward and honestly that's another question in it of itself. As for how to tell it to subtract that's what `diff` does.

Comment: This is perfect!  So how are you telling it to subtract one year from the previous year?  My only question, on perfecting it, is how can I make it so that it takes each consecutive year (2008 & 2009, 2009 & 2010, 2010 & 2011, etc.) and show their difference without a negative?  As in, regardless of the year, subtract the smaller from the larger.  Also, I'd like to have output like: 
2010-2011  303
2009-2010  795
etc.  I don't think it's necessary, but I'm curious if it's possible.

Comment: edited for absolute values, the rest of the question you'll need to look up yourself or ask another question because it's something entirely different

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("housing.csv")
# get occupied housing rows
df = df[df["title_field"] == "Occupied Housing Units"]
# pandas function which calculates rows difference
df["Diff"] = df.sort_values("years")["values"].diff()
# sort by value
df = df.sort_values("Diff", ascending=False)
```